# How can I solve $\lim_{x\to a}\; \frac{\cot(x)-\cot(a)}{x-a} $ without using L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Through some steps I got to this:

$$\lim_{x\to a}\; \frac{\frac{\cos(x)\sin(a)-\cos(a)\sin(x)}{x-a}}{\sin(x)\sin(a)}$$

The denominator is fine because if I place in $a$, I get $\sin^2(a)$. But the numerator should be $-1$ which I can't calculate without using the rule. I can't continue from here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know ?$$cos(x)*sin(a)-cos(a)*sin(x)=sin(a-x)$$

Comment: Nope, it was not on my cheatsheet. Thanks. Would you care to put this as an answer?

Comment: Isn't it the definition of the derivative of ${\rm cotg\,} x$ at $x=a$?

Comment: @TitoEliatron it is in the question that I can't use derivatives.

Comment: The limit is the defintion of the derivative of the function $\cot(x)$ at $x=a.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\cot x-\cot a}{x-a}=(\cot x)'|_{x=a}=-\frac1{\sin^2 a}=-\csc^2(a)$$

**Another way**:

$$\frac{\cot x-\cot a}{x-a}=\frac{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac{\cos a}{\sin a}}{x-a}=\frac{\sin a\cos x-\sin x\cos a}{(x-a)\sin x\sin a}=$$

$$\stackrel{\text{Trig. Identity}}=-\frac{\sin(a-x)}{a-x}\cdot\frac1{\sin x\sin a}\xrightarrow[x\to a]{}\stackrel{\text{known limit+continuity}}(-1)\cdot\frac1{\sin^2a}=-\csc^2(a)$$

Comment: Can I ask how the minus got there at the second line?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand.